# 'ListSerializer' object has no attribute 'error'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to save 300 objects through a DRF API, having a function executed on a POST request and storing all returned elements.

It seems like I am using the wrong type of serializer based on this error: `'ListSerializer' object has no attribute 'error'`

This is the model I created initially:

```
class Card(models.Model): 
game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image_numbers = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

This is my serializer:

```
class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
class Meta: 
    model = Card
    fields = (
        'game', 
        'image_numbers'
    )
```

This is the view class:

```
class CardsView (APIView): 
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

#Combination Generation Formula
def nth_combination(self, iterable, r, index):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    c = math.comb(n, r)
    if index < 0:
        index += c
    if index < 0 or index >= c:
        raise IndexError
    result = []
    while r:
        c, n, r = c*r//n, n-1, r-1
        while index >= c:
            index -= c
            c, n = c*(n-r)//n, n-1
        result.append(pool[-1-n])
    return tuple(result)

#Combination generation function with parametrizied sample (300 combs, 1-64 range, 16 items each)
def generate_combinations(self, game):
    n = 64
    r = 16
    iterable = range(1, n)
    n_combos = math.comb(len(iterable), r)
    indices = random.sample(range(n_combos), k=300) 
    combos = [[self.nth_combination(iterable, r, i), game] for i in indices]
    return combos

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Card.objects.all()
    serializer = CardSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data  
    serializer = CardSerializer(data = self.generate_combinations(request.data), many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.error)
```

The logic here is that on a POST request to my /cards endpoint, I generate 300 combinations of 16 items each, and I pair each combination with an extra value which is the 'game' value, taken from the request itself, e.g:

```
  {
        "id": 1,
        "game": 1,
        "image_numbers": [2, 7, 34, 45, 54, 33, 2, 5, 22, 11, 24, 51, 15, 41, 23, 16]
    },
```

Then, I'm trying to serialize and save all the generated items. What I'm not really sure about is if I'm passing the returned data from generate_combinations() to the serializer properly.

```
Traceback error: 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/django/drfproj/drfproj/views.py", line 85, in post
    return Response(serializer.error)
AttributeError: 'ListSerializer' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: This may just be a simple typo.  Try `.errors` instead of `.error`.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGordon it was indeed a Typo. Now I'm getting the following response for every record I try to save: [{"game":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received QueryDict."]},

Hence my doubt about passing data to the serializer properly seems like it's not receiving either 'game' or the generated combination.